# MYSQL - Storing BLOBS or dynamic schema?

Tags: mysql, database, matlab, database-design, blob

I have a, for me, hard problem since I'm not very experienced in creating databases. I have a summer internship at a company that wants me to create a database for them. They're currently saving MATLAB structs on the server in the filesystem but want to move on to a MYSQL-database. It's my assignment to create this database.

The MATLAB-structs contain information about certain tests. A test results in a 5D array. Three of these dimensions are used as identifiers (in reality they are temperature, frequency and one more thing that I don't know what it is). Given these three dimensions, one gets a table with columnheaders that vary between tests. This table contains the testresults.

My idea was to store each resulting table as a BLOB in one table and use the identifiers to access each table together with a testid.

Is this a good idea? How would one usually go about storing 5D arrays, or tables that have columns that vary?

---

Example of data, matlab struct:

[image: exampleteststruct]

The 4D arrays are results from changing the frequency, rfFreq_GHz.

Comment: Give us a short sample of the data.

Comment: @RickJames Included sample data in post.

Comment: What will you do with the table?  That is, what will the `SELECT` look like?

Comment: I'll query by DUT and measurementScript. All fields except DUT, measurementXXX and info change between tests. We don't have a official structure yet it seems.
Is it bad practice to store the variable fields of the struct as binary in a field in the db?

Comment: If you don't need to filter (`WHERE`), sort (`ORDER BY`), etc a value, then it can be hidden in a 'binary' (XML, JSON, struct, etc).  Otherwise, hiding it makes MySQL's work quite difficult and slow.  (Hence my question about `SELECT`.)